# Basic OnClickListener not working in Android studio, Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn Android Studio, and am making a basic OnClickListener. My project has an xml file containing various buttons, edit texts and check boxes. I am trying to make a single OnClickListener to be used by the three checkboxes. However, when I run the code below the only Toast message that appears says 'other', regardless of which box is pressed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CheckBox maleBox, femaleBox, otherBox;

        maleBox = findViewById(R.id.maleBox);
        femaleBox = findViewById(R.id.femaleBox);
        otherBox = findViewById(R.id.otherBox);

        maleBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        femaleBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        otherBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.maleBox:
                Toast.makeText(this, "man", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            case R.id.femaleBox:
                Toast.makeText(this, "female", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            case R.id.otherBox:
                Toast.makeText(this, "other", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is occuring?
Many thanks,

Comment: since you are missing the break statment, all toasts are displayed, but only the last one will be shown, since it overlays all the others

Comment: therefore only "other" is shown

Comment: why not use setOnCheckedChangeListener? setOnCheckedChangeListener could better to processe the CheckBox click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one of the case is matched in a switch statement, then it is the responsibility of the programmer to decide whether following cases after that 'case' must be executed or not, that flow of following cases can be stopped by using break; statement
try below switch code,

```
    switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.maleBox:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "man", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.femaleBox:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "female", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.otherBox:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "other", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
```

In your scenario, the last toast is covering up the other toasts as it is the last case which will get executed every time, due to above explained reason

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `break` from your code.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.maleBox:
                Toast.makeText(this, "man", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.femaleBox:
                Toast.makeText(this, "female", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.otherBox:
                Toast.makeText(this, "other", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Read about switch [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-switch)

Answer (score 1):

your code :
`CheckBox maleBox, femaleBox, otherBox;`

CheckBox dont suggest to use `setOnClickListener`, should use setOnCheckedChangeListener()

```
    void onCreate(){
        //..
        maleBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        femaleBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        otherBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.maleBox:
                Toast.makeText(this, "man", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.femaleBox:
                Toast.makeText(this, "female", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.otherBox:
                Toast.makeText(this, "other", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: i think, ironically, this solves an entirely different issue